# Multiple root Newton-Raphson. Please help?

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

I'm really trying to understand this. The paper says:

> At a multiple root, the Newton-Raphson method converges linearly (I get that). The method is given by:
>
> $$x_{i+1} = x_{i} - m {f(x_{i})\over f'(x_{i})}$$
>
> Where $\space m \space$ is the multiplicity of the root, will restore quadratic convergence at such a root.

Here is what I don't understand.

I have been told to write a program in Maple (if that helps) that approximates $\space m \space$.

But isn't $\space x_{i+1} \space$ recursive?

I am given the value of $\space x_{0} \space$. But $\space x_{i+1} \space$ is still unknown because we don't know $\space m \space$.

Can someone help me please?
I hope I'm making sense.

Thank You.

Comment: It *is* recursive, you simply can't know $x_{i+1}$ immediately from $x_0$. But you can let the programme do that (pseudo): `for k in range(i): x = x-m*f(x)/f'(x)`.

Comment: @Vim - Thank you for responding. Can you please expand on that code.

Comment: do you know how value-assigning works in a programme? `x=g(x)` is an value assigning expression instead of a mathematical statement, so it means "update x with the new value f(x)". Such "updates" are what Newton method is.

Comment: @Vim - Yeah I know. I meant is what you typed down a for loop? Please forgive my slowness haha. I'm not very quick to catch things.

Comment: the for loop carries out i iterations and get the value of x_i+1, assuming x_0 is given.

Comment: @Vim - Thank you for your responses. I've just tried that now and turns out I can only solve for $m$ once $x_{n+1}$ is given. Not sure what my lecturer means by find an approximation of $m$ when he's only given $x_0$.

Comment: Ok I misread your question sorry. It seems you're confused about $m$ which I just assumed known. I think it might help if you can clarify what the muliplicitu of the root means.

Comment: @Vim - Sorry about that. For example a polynomial $(x-2)^n$ has root at $x = 2$. The multiplicity of the root is $n$.

Comment: so, how does it extend to non polynomial functions? Am I right in saying that a root $z$ has multiplicity $r$ if $f^{(n)}(z)=0,n=0,1,2,\cdots, r-1$ and $f^{(r)}(z)\ne 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let be $e_n=\left\vert x_{n+1}-x_n\right\vert$. You can estimate the value of $m$ considering $$e_{n+1}=\frac{m-1}{m}e_n.$$ Just make two normal Newton steps and use $x_0,x_1,x_2$ to evaluate the two succesive errors. The first steps of any iterative method may not be very good, specially in multiple roots, so you can discard $x_0,x_1$ and take two additional steps before approximate $m$.

Deepening a little more: if a function $f$ has a multiple root $r$ with multiplicity $m$, then $f$ is of the form $$f(x)=(x-r)^mg(x)$$ with necessarly $g(r)\neq 0$ and $f^\prime(x)=f^{\prime\prime}(x)=\cdots =f^{(m-1)}(x)=0$.  Let be $u(x)=f(x)/f^\prime (x)$. The function $u(x)$ has only one root (easy to proof) and you can use the iteration $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{u(x)}{u^\prime (x)}$$ and it converges cuadratically.

Also you can dynamically estimate $m$ with 
$$m=\max\left\{1, INT\left(\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{u(x_n)-u(x_{n-1})}\right)\right\}$$ as William Kahan suggest.